# Lambda S3 Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Im trying to load file to s3 bucket that i created and to trigger my lambda function that reads file content and sends it to another location .
When I upload with the console when i loged in with my aws user  everything works , but when I try to post a file to s3 externaly , for example using postman I succeed to upload the file to s3 bucket and also trigger my function but my lambda function throws an 403 error permission error to read and parse file content .

I tried to add policy permission to the bucket and also s3FullAccess rule to the lambda function but did not work 
Also set permissions directly to a file in postman post   header  acl parameters public-read permissions and nothing 
Please help .

**UPDATE**
This is the rule I attached to my lambda function for s3 all access:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Also granted Public access to Everyone in my s3 bucket: for read list and write

and on postman i added to the file this headers:

**Content-Type** : multipart/form-data
**x-amz-acl**: public-read-write

Please tell me what another information do you need for me in order to help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: to echo @Bsquare, specifically we would need to see the policy document on the s3 bucket, and the one applied to the lambda function's role.  plus any other relevant configuration.

Comment: @AlphaGeek  I updated my question with the relevant  more data for the permissions.Thanks